# ASP.net code telerik:RadScheduler not working on apple [ safari / chrome ]

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, telerik

This code show appointment schedule like the image i provided :

[image: 1]

but it didn't appear on apple [ safari / chrome ]

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-11"> <script type="text/javascript"> Sys.Application.add_load(function () { demo.scheduler = $find("<%= RadScheduler1.ClientID %>"); }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script> <script src="TelerikCode.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

i cant understand the problem so i didn't try any solution

Comment: <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">


           <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
          
            Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                demo.scheduler = $find("<%= RadScheduler1.ClientID %>");
            });
         
        </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
       <script src="TelerikCode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>

Comment: also this code is responsible for controlling the appointment buttons shown on the screen

Comment: Please add your ASP markup for the radscheduler. Do you have a transcriptmanager on the page? Where is that declared in relation to your radscheduler? What exactly isn't happening/working?